# javascript object initializers, usage of

Tags: javascript, oop, object, literals, object-literal

In the javascript [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers) for some reason there is a paragraph on object literal usage as follows:

"If an object is created with an object initializer in a top-level script, JavaScript interprets the object each time it evaluates an expression containing the object literal. In addition, an initializer used in a function is created each time the function is called."

I know what object literals are ie

```
var myObject = {...}
var myArray = [...]
```

etc.

I just can't envision a piece of working code that uses the above line/notion in mind when coding. Any examples of code that are engineered around this idea for a better understanding would be helpful.

Comment: JavaScript object literals are *ubiquitous* in production code. It's a tremendously convenient feature of the language. In fact I'm not sure where you'd find much serious code that *doesn't* rely on them heavily.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question

Comment: I agree :) All that's saying is that an object literal expression is an expression, and like any other expression it's evaluated as part of evaluating the code context it appears in.

Comment: That paragraph is worded terribly, I'll grant you that. Thankfully, MDN is a Wiki :)

Comment: Is there any better documentation that would surpass MDN. But then again why can't MDN provide good official documentation as PHP and Python do?

Comment: Well MDN is usually OK, and I just (hopefully) improved that paragraph by replacing it with one that I think makes sense.

Comment: so basically there is more behind the scenes work when using object initializers. Nevertheless it's more convenient.

Comment: Well you can expect that a modern JavaScript runtime will do a pretty good job of handling that efficiently. If you need a new object with initialized properties, you've got to do the work one way or another.

Comment: it's just trying to say that []==new Array(); you don't save anything by using literals like you might have with RegExps back in the day, or string literals in many languages.